# Apache 403 when hitting name.local Yosemite

Tags: macos, apache, osx-yosemite, http-status-code-403, apache2.4

This is the first time I'm setting up an apache web server, I'm doing this on my Mac with OS X Yosemite. For some reason I'm receiving 403 errors when I try to hit my user directory via the browser with the formate computerName.local. When I hit the default directory with that same format I get the "It works!" page, but when I try to hit my user directory it gives me the "Forbidden" error... If I hit it with localhost everything works fine, but I'm trying to hit it from my iPhone hence the localhost won't work from there...

I've tried every guide I could find, tried setting the vhosts configuration file (but when I do so the browser can't reach the folder even when trying localhost), I tried changing the httpd.conf file to have "Require all granted" on a new  with the path to my user sites directory... Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong? If you need I could upload my httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf files (or any other related file that may need configuration).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It took me a while but it was really simple at the end. On my User conf file /private/etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf there was a line that was absolutely responsible for the behavior that from localhost everything worked fine but from computerName.local it wouldn't. This is what the file looked like:

```
<Directory "/Users/Santiago/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    LanguagePriority en fr de
    ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All I had to do was change that "Allow from localhost" to "Allow from all" and restart apache. Everything works now.